# Custom EditText into Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to put attach file icon into EditText for example how it was made into WhatsApp. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drawableRight` attribute in EditText

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/account_et"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_backall" //your drawable which you want to use
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/str_md_email"
android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Okay, but how he's bind listener by icon click?

Comment: for drawable left or right click,have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26269435/5110595)

Answer (score 7):

#### That is not a custom EditBox. Here `EditText` is wrapped with parent view with other `ImageViews`.

In whatsapp example there is a **Imogi ImageView**, **An EditText**, **An Attach ImageView**, and **a camera ImageView** inside a `LinearLayout`. And parent `LinearLayout` is having round corner background.

- You **can also use Drawable left** and Drawable right, but **I will not suggest** that because that does not have much control.

#### Just a suggestion:

I always want to save time. Here is an whatsapp clone, you can just pull it and use its views.

https://github.com/Shahar2k5/whatsappClone

This guy has done good work in this library.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to manage like below image :

[image]

For above UI design code is below :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/stockbg"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_sendMeassage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_send"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_next_arrow"
                    android:tint="@color/color_gray" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to put attach file icon into EditText for example how it was made into WhatsApp.

if you want to add icon in `EditText` you can use

```
android:drawableStart=""
android:drawableEnd=""
android:drawableTop=""
android:drawableLeft=""
android:drawableRight=""
```

> how it was made into WhatsApp. How can I do it?

That is not Custom `Edittext`

You need to wrap your  `ImageView` and  `EditText` in side a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout`  or `RelativeLayout`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> ```
>    android:background="@drawable/test"
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put edittext and attach icon in layout (according to your need) and set rounded background to parent layout

like this

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/roundedbg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/attachFile"
         android:background="@null"
            android:padding="@dimen/five_dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/attachFile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
       />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

roundedbg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

better you use wrap edittext and imageview in relative layout like below

```
     <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:minLines="10"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPasswordToggle"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

**output :**

[image]

in java code use click on `imageview`